# Can I wget the result from the javascript generated webpage

Tags: javascript, json, linux, wget

the url link : https://live.eservice-hk.net/viutv

will return the text results (one text line) and show it on the browser.

I wanna to get those results via wget but I can't.

Then I watch the website page source and discovered that the page was generated by javascript.

How do I get the results instead of the javascript?

Comment: What have you tried? Supply us with some code you made? It will be easier to solve your problem if we have your code :)

Comment: no, with wget you can't do this. you need a browser engine (web driver) for this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: @Granny : I have tried the command "wget https:/......." but I cannot get the result instead of a html file including the script 

But I access the URL above in the browser , the browser return the correct result .

Comment: @Dwhitz : Sorry about that. I'm new to stackoverflow  but what all I have tried is search this site and get no good results ....therefore I post my question to here.... , let me know if there is anything need improved

Comment: You'd need to fetch the page with wget and then run that through a JavaScript interpreter (like "SeaMonkey"), but external JS libraries and the DOM are additional issues you would need to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No! You cannot** `wget` (or even `curl`) the *dynamically* generated javascript result from the page. You need a *webdriver* like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) for that or maybe use [Chrome in Headless Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).

**But** for that particular page (and more specifically for that particular text result), you can use `curl` to get the text-link:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"channelno":"099","deviceId":"0000anonymous_user","format":"HLS"}' https://api.viu.now.com/p8/1/getLiveURL | jq '.asset.hls.adaptive[0]'
```

*Note*: The `POST` data and link is taken from the page's source. [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a nice, little command line utility to handle JSON data on command line.